# Replace text in OpenOffice text document by an image using java

Tags: java, servlets, uno, odt

I have a template in .odt extension and want to populate data in the same by replacing patterned text and save it into pdf or doc.

Have no issue in replacing text by the text and saving into doc/pdf but having trouble to replace text by an image.

For example:

Template having following patterns to be replaced by image and text

---

```
//------some static content-------

**&<**signature will be replaced by image.png**>&**

**&<**name of person will be replaced by normal text**>&**
```

---

`*&<*` , `*>&*` are pattern identifiers in template.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample java code to replace text with image (Signature) in odt template and generate doc/pdf file.**

```
package com.newgen.doc;

import com.sun.star.awt.Point;
import com.sun.star.awt.Size;
import com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue;
import com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet;
import com.sun.star.bridge.XUnoUrlResolver;
import com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap;
import com.sun.star.container.XNameContainer;
import com.sun.star.drawing.XShape;
import com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader;
import com.sun.star.frame.XController;
import com.sun.star.frame.XStorable;
import com.sun.star.io.IOException;
import com.sun.star.lang.XComponent;
import com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory;
import com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory;
import com.sun.star.text.XPageCursor;
import com.sun.star.text.XText;
import com.sun.star.text.XTextContent;
import com.sun.star.text.XTextCursor;
import com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument;
import com.sun.star.text.XTextRange;
import com.sun.star.text.XTextViewCursor;
import com.sun.star.text.XTextViewCursorSupplier;
import com.sun.star.uno.UnoRuntime;

import com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext;
import com.sun.star.uno.XInterface;
import com.sun.star.util.CloseVetoException;
import com.sun.star.util.XCloseable;
import com.sun.star.util.XReplaceDescriptor;
import com.sun.star.util.XReplaceable;
import com.sun.star.util.XSearchDescriptor;
import com.sun.star.util.XSearchable;


public class GenerateDocWithSignature {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String templateUrl = "File:///C:/temp/Test.odt";
        String signatureImg = "file:///C:/temp/signature.jpg";
        GenerateDocWithSignature graphicExample = new GenerateDocWithSignature();
        boolean pdfFlag = true;
        try {
            graphicExample.addSignature(templateUrl, signatureImg, pdfFlag);
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please check Exception::" + e);            
        } finally {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    protected void addSignature(String templateUrl, String signatureImg, boolean pdfFlag) {
        XMultiComponentFactory xRemoteServiceManager = null;
        XTextRange xTextRange = null;
        XTextViewCursorSupplier supTextViewCursor = null;
        XController xController = null;
        Object obj = null;
        XComponent xComp = null;

        String openOfficePort = "8100";//"2001";
        String conDesc = "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=" + openOfficePort + ";urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager";
        XComponentContext xContext = getXComponentContext();
        xRemoteServiceManager = xContext.getServiceManager();
        try {
            obj = xRemoteServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", xContext);
            XUnoUrlResolver xUnoUrlResolver = (XUnoUrlResolver) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XUnoUrlResolver.class, obj);
            obj = xUnoUrlResolver.resolve(conDesc);
            xRemoteServiceManager = (XMultiComponentFactory) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XMultiComponentFactory.class, obj);

            Object desktop = xRemoteServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext);
            XComponentLoader xComponentLoader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class, desktop);

            PropertyValue[] loadProps = new PropertyValue[1];
            loadProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
            loadProps[0].Name = "Hidden";
            loadProps[0].Value = true;

            xComp = xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL(templateUrl, "_blank", 0, loadProps);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception::"+e);
        }

        // Get XTextDocument from template
        XTextDocument xTextDoc = (XTextDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, xComp);

        // Get Current Controller
        xController = xTextDoc.getCurrentController();
        supTextViewCursor = (XTextViewCursorSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextViewCursorSupplier.class, xController);
        XTextViewCursor curTextView = supTextViewCursor.getViewCursor();

        // Get page cursor and assigns XTextViewCursor cursor to page
        XPageCursor curPage = (XPageCursor) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPageCursor.class, curTextView);
        System.out.println("The current page number is " + curPage.getPage());

        // Querying for the interface XMultiServiceFactory on the XTextDocument
        XMultiServiceFactory xMSFDoc = (XMultiServiceFactory) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XMultiServiceFactory.class, xTextDoc);

        // Get XText
        XText xText = xTextDoc.getText();

        XReplaceDescriptor xReplaceDescr = null;
        XSearchDescriptor xSearchDescr = null;
        XReplaceable xReplaceable = null;
        XSearchable xSearchable = null;
        XStorable xStorable = null;
        xReplaceable = (XReplaceable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XReplaceable.class, xTextDoc);
        xReplaceDescr = xReplaceable.createReplaceDescriptor();
        xSearchable = (XSearchable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSearchable.class, xTextDoc);
        xSearchDescr = xSearchable.createSearchDescriptor();
        xSearchDescr.setSearchString("Signature");
        Point point = null;
        // Search String and get its first occurrence and get  XInterface
        XInterface xInterface = (XInterface) xSearchable.findFirst(xSearchDescr);
        System.out.println("XInterface=" + xInterface);
        if (xInterface != null) {
            System.out.println("XInterface-->" + xInterface.toString());
            xTextRange = (com.sun.star.text.XTextRange) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    com.sun.star.text.XTextRange.class, xInterface);
            System.out.println("xTextRange-->" + xTextRange.getString());
            curTextView.gotoRange(xTextRange, false);

            //get cursor position
            point = curTextView.getPosition();
            System.out.println("Point X=" + point.X + " Y=" + point.Y);
        }

        XTextCursor xTextCursor = (com.sun.star.text.XTextCursor) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                com.sun.star.text.XTextCursor.class, xInterface);

        try {
            // Creating graphic shape service
            Object graphicObjShape = null;
            graphicObjShape = xMSFDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicObjectShape");

            // Customizing graphic shape position and size
            XShape shapeSettings = (XShape) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XShape.class, graphicObjShape);
            shapeSettings.setSize(new Size(600, 600));
        //shapeSettings.setPosition(point);

            // Creating bitmap container service
            XNameContainer bitmapContainer = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XNameContainer.class,
                    xMSFDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.BitmapTable"));
            // Inserting test image to the container
            bitmapContainer.insertByName("Signature", signatureImg);
            // Querying for the interface XPropertySet on the graphic object
            XPropertySet xPropSet = (XPropertySet) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, graphicObjShape);

            System.out.println("Test img url is" + bitmapContainer.getByName("Signature"));

            // Setting Signature image internal URL to graphic shape property
            xPropSet.setPropertyValue("GraphicURL", bitmapContainer.getByName("Signature"));

            // Convert graphic shape to the text content item
            XTextContent xTextContent = (XTextContent) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextContent.class, graphicObjShape);

            // Embed image into the document text with replacement
            System.out.println("Inserting image...");
            xText.insertTextContent(xTextCursor, xTextContent, true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception::" + e);
        }

        //close
        PropertyValue[] storeProps = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String newFileName = null;
        try {
            xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, xTextDoc);
            if (!pdfFlag) {
                if (templateUrl.substring(templateUrl.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
                    xStorable.store();
                } else {
                    fileName = templateUrl.substring(0, templateUrl.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    storeProps = new PropertyValue[1];
                    storeProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
                    storeProps[0].Name = "FilterName";
                    storeProps[0].Value = "MS Word 97";
                    xStorable.storeToURL(fileName + ".doc", storeProps);
                    newFileName = fileName + ".doc";
                }
            } else {
                fileName = templateUrl.substring(0, templateUrl.lastIndexOf('.'));
                storeProps = new PropertyValue[1];
                storeProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
                storeProps[0].Name = "FilterName";
                storeProps[0].Value = "writer_pdf_Export";
                xStorable.storeToURL(fileName + ".pdf", storeProps);
                newFileName = fileName + ".pdf";
            }
            System.out.println("Document generated-->" + newFileName);
            XCloseable xCloseable = (XCloseable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCloseable.class, xTextDoc);
            xCloseable.close(true);
        } catch (IOException | CloseVetoException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception::"+e);
        }
    }


    private XComponentContext getXComponentContext() {
        XComponentContext xContext = null;
        XMultiComponentFactory xRemoteServiceManager = null;

        String openOfficePort = "";

        try {
            xContext = Bootstrap.createInitialComponentContext(null);
            System.out.println("xContext=" + xContext);
            openOfficePort = "8100";//"2001";

            String DefCon = "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=" + openOfficePort + ";urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager";

            xRemoteServiceManager = xContext.getServiceManager();

            Object obj = xRemoteServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", xContext);
            XUnoUrlResolver xUnoUrlResolver = (XUnoUrlResolver) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XUnoUrlResolver.class, obj);

            obj = xUnoUrlResolver.resolve(DefCon);

            xRemoteServiceManager = (XMultiComponentFactory) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XMultiComponentFactory.class, obj);
            XPropertySet xPropertySet = (XPropertySet) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, xRemoteServiceManager);

            obj = xPropertySet.getPropertyValue("DefaultContext");
            xContext = (XComponentContext) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentContext.class, obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception::"+e);
        }
        System.out.println("xContext="+xContext);
        return xContext;
    }

}
```